# Create data.frame with 100 random samplings of a column in another data.frame

Tags: r

I'm working with a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", ...), 
                 b = c(10, 20, 30, ...))
```

I would like to create a new data frame that consists of 100 columns each of which contains a different random selection of 250 genes from column `a` of the original data frame. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
data.frame(matrix(data = df[sample(nrow(df), 250), 1], 
                  ncol = 100, nrow = 250))
```

However, this populates every column with the same random sampling rather than a unique one.

Comment: Use `replicate(100, sample...)`. Your 'sample' expression is good. You can wrap the whole thing with `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great!

Comment: The `data` you're supplying to `matrix` has fewer elements than the dimensions create, so it's getting recycled. Depending on what you want in terms of replacement, you can just increase the sample size to match, e.g. `sample(nrow(df), 100 * 250)`

Comment: Someone want to add answer with explanation?

Comment: Any way to include the seed used for each random sampling as the column header?

Comment: Maybe `simplify2array(sapply(seq(10), function(i){set.seed(i); setNames(list(sample(mtcars$mpg, 5)), i)}))`, but if you set the seed beforehand the whole thing is reproducible regardless.

Comment: I edited my answer to handle seeds in column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go, with 10 instead of 100 and 5 instead of 250

```
df <- data.frame(a = paste0("gene",1:100), 
                 b = seq(10,100,10))
random_samples <- replicate(10,df[sample(nrow(df), 5), 1])

# [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]     [,10]   
# [1,] "gene14" "gene100" "gene13" "gene5"  "gene20" "gene68" "gene24" "gene57" "gene54" "gene44"
# [2,] "gene71" "gene67"  "gene44" "gene25" "gene90" "gene45" "gene46" "gene69" "gene76" "gene3" 
# [3,] "gene54" "gene34"  "gene97" "gene67" "gene10" "gene50" "gene62" "gene54" "gene49" "gene58"
# [4,] "gene81" "gene18"  "gene50" "gene60" "gene56" "gene7"  "gene42" "gene82" "gene50" "gene51"
# [5,] "gene12" "gene71"  "gene31" "gene19" "gene50" "gene2"  "gene15" "gene95" "gene59" "gene23"

# with seeds 
seeds <- 1:10
seeds %>% sapply(function(x){set.seed(x);df[sample(nrow(df), 5), 1]}) %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(paste0("S",seeds))

#          S1     S2     S3     S4     S5     S6     S7     S8     S9    S10
#          1 gene27 gene19 gene17 gene59 gene21 gene61 gene99 gene47 gene23 gene51
#          2 gene37 gene70 gene80  gene1 gene68 gene93 gene40 gene21  gene3 gene31
#          3 gene57 gene57 gene38 gene29 gene90 gene26 gene12 gene79 gene21 gene42
#          4 gene89 gene17 gene32 gene27 gene28 gene37  gene7 gene64 gene98 gene68
#          5 gene20 gene91 gene58 gene79 gene11 gene78 gene24 gene31 gene43  gene9
```